# Rendering part of component only on few routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my application and I'm using react-router.On every route I have rendered Navbar and in the Navbar I have input field which I want to render only on two routes. How can I do it ? Is there any "If" that can I use to render part of component when route is matched ?

Comment: You can use package "npm i react-if-elseif-else-render" . If you want to use IF Else conditions for your code than take reference from this "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-if-elseif-else-render"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Route` you will have a collection of `RouteParams` (match, location and history). You can use e.g. the location.pathname to conditionally render whatever you want.

Something like:

```
<Router>
  <Route render={({match,location,history})=>{
    const showNavFields = location.pathname==='/your-path'
    return {
     <NavBar showNavFields={showNavFields}/>  
    }
 }}/>
 <Switch>
   <Route path="/your-path" component="AComponent"/ >
   <Route path="/your-other-path" component="AnotherComponent"/ >
 </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: But what when my NavBar is outside of all routes ? It is in <Router> but outside of any <Route> so it will show on all routes.

Comment: As long as it isn't in a <Switch>, the above Route will match on all routes (and so will show regarless of whether other other Routes at the same level match or not). You can then conditionally render whatever you like inside it.

Comment: The crucial part with match,location, history is not working, my IDE shows me that there is an error, probably something with braces but in this code I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Ok I know what was wrong, return in your answer should have () not {}. But expect that all works very good :D

Answer (score 1):

We can use match.url for that.

Working code. Here we are appending `route matched` to router url if route is `/topics/rendering`

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Topics({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Topics</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Route path={`${match.path}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
      <Route
        exact
        path={match.path}
        render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function Topic({ match }) {
  if (match.url === '/topics/rendering') {
    return (
    <div>
      <h3>route matched {match.params.topicId}</h3>
    </div>
  )
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
      </div>
    )

  }

}

export default BasicExample;
```

Comment: My NavBar is outside of all routes. It is in <Router> but outside of any <Route> so it will show on all routes. So I think that i won't have access to match yes ? What should I do then ?

Comment: If you are redirected for route defined using `<Route />` component, then you have access to match but if it is not defined using `<Route />`, you can use `withRouter` HOC to wrap your component. `withRouter` gives you access to location, history and match object to the component being wrapped. [Link to help you understand more](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter)